# Define Gauntlet in "the gauntlet of..."

Tags: meaning

> Human tests—called clinical trials—are the gauntlet of drug
>   development , and have three phases

What does "gauntlet" mean in the above context?

"throw down the gauntlet" is an idiom "to issue a challenge" where gauntlet refers to a type of glove. In the above extract the word gauntlet alone has been used as a noun, what does it mean there?

Answer (score 15):

Two separate words, although they're spelled and pronounced the same.  The first "gauntlet" comes to us through the French for glove, and it refers to hand armor.  Go [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=gantlet&es_sm=91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIubamqYyZyAIVwnQ-Ch037QOD&biw=1425&bih=781#tbm=isch&q=steel%20gauntlets) for pictures.  Tossing one's glove before an opponent was a challenge to fight, thus the idiom meaning to challenge.  The second "gauntlet" was originally "gantlope," which comes from the Swedish *gatlopp*, literally "gate passage" and refers to a punishment of forcing someone to run between two lines of people who struck the unfortunate runner.  Thus the word's use as a trial or ordeal.  The *OED* suggests that the word entered English during the Thirty Years War and lost its pronunciation to the first gauntlet.

To makes things worse, there's also the word "gantlet," which is the configuration of two railroad lines that have to share a narrow passage.  Go [here](https://www.handlaidtrack.com/assets/images/gantlet-schematic.png) for a diagram and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauntlet_track#/media/File:Sechsschienengleis.JPG) for a picture.

Comment: I wonder if the OP's source conflated the 2 senses of "running the gauntlet" -- the ordeal and "throwing down the gauntlet" -- the challenge.  The original senetence seems rather muddled suggesting at first reading an armoured fist developing drugs rather than the meanings of either of the familiar phrases.

Comment: I favor the "running the gauntlet" interpretation—human drug trials can be a long ordeal, but not a deathmatch.

Comment: The "running" interpretation is the only one that makes sense to me, but I would have much preferred the quoted passage to have been phrased so that the word "run" actually appeared.

Comment: The railroad "*gantlet*" is a specific instance of the "running the gauntlet" meaning of the term, and in fact some dictionaries list "*gantlet*" as an alternative spelling for that meaning.

Answer (score 8):

The reference is to [running the gauntlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_the_gauntlet), originally a form of punishment where the individual was made to run between two rows of soldiers who would punch and beat him as he ran, but now more often taken to refer to a stressful and reasonably protracted period of tests or exercises.

Answer (score 0):

The gauntlet of drug development is a use of "Running the gauntlet."

From: https://american-history.net/native-america/native-american-life/native-american-rituals/
‘Run the gauntlet’ has become a well-known phrase today. This phrase is actually inspired from the Native American ritual of ‘Gauntlet’.

Gauntlet is a ritual which was performed to punish the guilty member of a tribe for some crime he or she had committed. In this ritual, two rows of warriors stood facing each other and holding sticks.

The guilty person had to run between the rows. As he or she ran, the warriors on both sides whipped the person with sticks as punishment for their crimes.
End of reference.

There was also a tradition of American Indians using a milder form of the process to initiate a new member, perhaps even captured, into the tribe. Beating them as they ran the length of the row was to get out any and all the anger or resistance the members had to the new individual. When they completed the challenge they were helped and injuries looked after as they were now part of the group. Still looking for reference.

Answer (score -4):

<del>I think "gauntlet" here carries the sense of a tool/means to achieving a desired end (i.e. drug development here). The author's statement isn't neutral or benign; "gauntlet" packs a pejorative connotation, because a gauntlet is not some fuzzy wool glove keeping you warm, but part of knight's armor to stay protected in combat and deliver punishment. So this word choice evokes a scenario of combat/punishment and seems to frame clinical testing as a (violent) manipulation of its human objects.</del>

Comment: That sounds like pure speculation.

Comment: That awkward moment when you re-read an answer that you had written [the night before]; you wrinkle your brow, thinking, "nice try, but this person is way off base here," so you go to downvote it. But the system returns an error message because "you can't vote for your own post". An awkward silence ensues...and ensues...and ensues. **The ambien walrus has struck again.**

Comment: Yup. Been there.

Comment: Why isn't that moment quickly followed by the swift clicking of the mouse on the "delete" link?

Comment: @GreenAsJade I probably would've deleted my original comment if it was later seen to be offensive. But I'm pretty sure that this one will sooner cause laughter than harm.

Comment: @GreenAsJade sidenote: it is a pet peeve of mine when people post things on the internet and go on to delete them if they weren't received as intended. I think it's kind of lame, but that's just me.

Comment: I think there are different valid views on that act.  One possibility is that you post something only to find out that you were genuinely mistaken.  So you learn from that - and then it's not doing anyone any good having your erroneous content there, so you delete it.   When I bump into an answer like yours I'm peeved that the author wasted my time in having me read it when they know that it's rubbish.   Better that it isn't there at all than even waste the space and precious seconds to read and reject known trash.   In this specific case, the potential for laughter might just offset that...

Comment: Had some of the same problem with my middle-of-the-night work when I'm up and can't sleep due to this #$%! screwed up rotator cuff.